# Ajax update with laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

Hi there I have this problem with my update so here is my blade code:

```
 <div class="form-group floating-label" id="role_colaboration1">
   <select name="{{$role}}[]" id="role"
           class="form-  control">
    <option value="2">Co-author</option>
    <option value="3">Contributor</option>
    <option value="4">Guest</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And here I have my ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#role").change(function(){
         var role_value = $(this).val();
            var bank_id =<?php echo json_encode($bank_id); ?>;

            $.ajax({

                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('/banks/change-role-in-bank') }}",
                data: {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    role_value: role_value,
                    bank_id: bank_id
                },
                success: function () {
                    $("select[id=role][value=" + role_value + "]");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
       });
    });
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/change-role-in-bank', 'BankController@changeRoleInBank');
```

And here I have my controller:

```
 public function  changeRoleInBank(){
       if(request()->ajax()) {
            $bank_id = request()->input('bank_id');
            $role = request()->input('role');

          $bank_invites = BankInvite::select('id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->get();
          $changeUserRole = BankInvitedUser::where('bank_invites_id', $bank_invites)->update(['role' => $role]);
            return response()->json(Lang::get('general.bank_deleted'));

      }
```

It is not updating What I am doing wrong..? is the ajax part

Comment: Did you debug through console to see if server throws errors?

Comment: add few console.log within javascript code, to see if javascript code is being fully executed. Wrap code within your php method with try/catch block, to catch any errors. Try to inject request as param within your method. I.e. changeRoleInBank(Request $request)

Comment: Is $bank_invites returning just one value or an array?

Comment: It must be returning an array as you are using `get()`. `$bank_invites = BankInvite::select('id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->get();`

Comment: replace get() with first() 
try the following code 
$bank_invites = BankInvite::select('id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->first();
          $changeUserRole = BankInvitedUser::where('bank_invites_id', $bank_invites->id)->update(['role' => $role]);

Comment: Please check my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check this editable code:

And here I have my controller:

```
public function  changeRoleInBank(){
       if(request()->ajax()) {
            $bank_id = request()->input('bank_id');
            $role = request()->input('role');

          $bank_invites = BankInvite::select('id')->where('bank_id', $bank_id)->first();
          $changeUserRole = BankInvitedUser::where('bank_invites_id', $bank_invites->id)->update(['role' => $role]);
            return response()->json(Lang::get('general.bank_deleted'));

      }
```

I just changed: **$bank_invites to $bank_invites->id**

```
$changeUserRole = BankInvitedUser::where('bank_invites_id', $bank_invites->id)->update(['role' => $role]);
```